# Compiling R under OSX with X11 Support

Tags: r, compilation, x11, xquartz

I am trying to compile the development version of R under OSX, but I cannot find the correct way to link to the X11 libraries. I think they are included in XQuartz, but linking to `/opt/X11/lib` or `/opt/X11/include/X11` using `./configure --x-libraries` still generates an error that the headers cannot be found.

What is the correct way to link to the X11 headers with a default XQuartz install?

Comment: are you following the example in the homebrew R formula? https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-science/blob/master/r.rb Also, you can use the r-devel pkg from AT&T http://r.research.att.com/ (it's easier than compiling IMO)

Comment: Try searching the archives of the r-sig-mac mailing list.

Comment: Thanks Carl I found some examples there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The X-specific options are both required `./configure --x-libraries=/opt/X11/lib/ --x-includes=/opt/X11/include` worked fine.